# Problem with search bar in JavaFX project (javaFX + h2 database, the "total" textField is not working with search bar), CRUD

Tags: java, javafx, h2

I have a problem with my JavaFX project. I have a search bar which works with my `TableView`. I created a "total" `TextField` which is supposed to show the total amount of all records in the table. BUT I mean all records, I mean all the ones that are there for example after filter records with search bar. Currently when I filter table records with search bar, the "total" `TextField` still is showing a total value of all records in this column in database, not the all ones being currently in the `TableView`. Can you look at it and help me find out, what should I do to make it work?

Here is my code:

```java
private void searchData() {
    FilteredList<Data> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(getDataList(), b -> true);
    search.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> filteredData.setPredicate(Data -> {
        if(newValue.isEmpty() || newValue.isBlank()) {
            return true;
        }
        String lowerCase = newValue.toLowerCase();
        if(Data.getName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase)) {
            return true;
        }
        else if(Data.getCategory().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase)) {
            return true;
        }
        else if(String.valueOf(Data.getPrice()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase)) {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return String.valueOf(Data.getDate()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase);
    }));
    SortedList<Data> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);
    sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(table.comparatorProperty());
    table.setItems(sortedData);
    total();
}
```

---

```
private void total() {
    int totalAmount = 0;
    totalAmount = table.getItems()
                       .stream()
                       .map((item) -> item.getPrice())
                       .reduce(totalAmount, (accumulation, _item) -> accumulation + _item);
    total.setText(String.valueOf(totalAmount));
}
```

Edit 1:

```
private void searchData() {
        FilteredList<Data> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(getDataList(), b -> true);
        search.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> filteredData.setPredicate(Data -> {

            if(newValue.isEmpty() || newValue.isBlank()) {
                total();
                return true;
            }
            String lowerCase = newValue.toLowerCase();

            if(Data.getName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase)) {
                total();
                return true;
            }
            else if(Data.getCategory().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase)) {
                total();
                return true;
            }
            else if(String.valueOf(Data.getPrice()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase)) {
                total();
                return true;
            }
            else if(String.valueOf(Data.getDate()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase)) {
                total();
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }));
        SortedList<Data> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);
        sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(table.comparatorProperty());
        table.setItems(sortedData);
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn’t you need to call `total()` inside the change listener, not outside it? You need to update the label when the table’s items change.

Comment: I've changed the code as you said, but the value in "total" is changing with some delay: when I put some letter in the search bar, the "total" textField is showing previous value, not current. What do you think about it? Look at my edit, I put new code there

Comment: Well now you have the call(s) to `total()` in the predicate(s). That doesn't make sense either. You need to compute the total *when the filter changes*, not when the predicate is executed.

Comment: what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Not sure I can say it any more clearly or precisely than I already did. Can you clarify what you don't understand?

Answer (score 3):

In your first attempt at the code, you call `total()` just once, when you register the listener with the search field's text property. The `total()` method won't ever be called again, so the total won't be updated when the items in the table change.

In the second attempt, you place calls to `total()` inside the actual predicates that are used to determine if elements should be included in the filtered list. You actually have no idea when these predicates will be executed: that is an internal implementation detail of `FilteredList`. The predicate should simply return `true` or `false`, depending on whether an element should be included in the list; having side-effects in those methods does not make sense.

You need to recompute the total every time the data change. One way to do this (*which assumes you are not changing the data anywhere else*) is to simply call `total()` in the listener for changes in the search field's text property:

```
private void searchData() {
    FilteredList<Data> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(getDataList(), b -> true);
    search.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        filteredData.setPredicate(Data -> {
            if(newValue.isEmpty() || newValue.isBlank()) {
                return true;
            }
            String lowerCase = newValue.toLowerCase();
            if(Data.getName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase)) {
                return true;
            }
            else if(Data.getCategory().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase)) {
                return true;
            }
            else if(String.valueOf(Data.getPrice()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase)) {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return String.valueOf(Data.getDate()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase);

        });

        total();

    });

    SortedList<Data> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);
    sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(table.comparatorProperty());
    table.setItems(sortedData);
    total();
}
```

The assumption that you are not changing the data anywhere else is probably too big an assumption. (Even if you are not doing so now, you might want to add functionality to add new data into your table, for example, and in that circumstance the total would not be updated when you add new data.) A better approach is to register a listener or a binding with the list. (This assumes you are not calling `table.setItems()` anywhere else in the code, but that is a reasonable assumption in most cases.)

You can do

```
private void searchData() {
    FilteredList<Data> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(getDataList(), b -> true);
    search.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        filteredData.setPredicate(Data -> {
            if(newValue.isEmpty() || newValue.isBlank()) {
                return true;
            }
            String lowerCase = newValue.toLowerCase();
            if(Data.getName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase)) {
                return true;
            }
            else if(Data.getCategory().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase)) {
                return true;
            }
            else if(String.valueOf(Data.getPrice()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase)) {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return String.valueOf(Data.getDate()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase);

        });

    });

    SortedList<Data> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);
    sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(table.comparatorProperty());
    table.setItems(sortedData);

    sortedData.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Data> c) -> total());
    total();
}
```

or with a binding:

```
private void searchData() {
    FilteredList<Data> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(getDataList(), b -> true);
    search.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        filteredData.setPredicate(Data -> {
            if(newValue.isEmpty() || newValue.isBlank()) {
                return true;
            }
            String lowerCase = newValue.toLowerCase();
            if(Data.getName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase)) {
                return true;
            }
            else if(Data.getCategory().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase)) {
                return true;
            }
            else if(String.valueOf(Data.getPrice()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase)) {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return String.valueOf(Data.getDate()).toLowerCase().contains(lowerCase);

        });

    });

    SortedList<Data> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);
    sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(table.comparatorProperty());
    table.setItems(sortedData);

    total.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(
        this::total,
        sortedData
    ));
}
```

The binding version requires the minor modification to the `total()` method:

```
private String total() {
    int totalAmount = table.getItems()
                       .stream()
                       //.map((item) -> item.getPrice())
                       //.reduce(totalAmount, (accumulation, _item) -> accumulation + _item);
                       // simplified code:
                       .mapToDouble(Data::getPrice)
                       .sum();
    return String.valueOf(totalAmount);
}
```